# structure config statements by writing to the config file

Tags: php, mysql, config, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am trying to insert database config statements into database.php but unable to structure it properly, i have missed single/double quotes and escape quotes as i have no idea how to escape $db and only localhost is printed to the file. Please guide as to how this is done. All config statements need to be printed to the file i.e database.php , now its printing only localhost.

```html
$data = $db['$username']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['$username']['username'] = 'root';
$db['$username']['password'] = '';
$db['$username']['database'] = '$username';
$db['$username']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['$username']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['$username']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['$username']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['$username']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['$username']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['$username']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['$username']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['$username']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['$username']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['$username']['stricton'] = FALSE;
    if ( ! write_file('../dropma/application/config/database.php', $data, 'a+'))
    {
            echo 'Unable to write the file';
    }
    else
    {
            echo 'File written!';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `$data`, pass `$db` :

```
write_file('../dropma/application/config/database.php', $db, 'a+')
```

Actually, according to the docs:

> https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/file_helper.html#write_file
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
>  $path (string) – File path 
>  $data (string) – Data to write to file 
>  $mode (string) – fopen() mode
> ```

The "$data" passed **should be a string**. Its not working because youre passing an array...

I should ask, why are you doing this? why are you creating that file ? and how/where is this script going be placed and executed? Maybe theres an easier way to accomplish what youre trying to do.

**UPDATE:**

Since you are trying to change your DB settings for your different environments (dev, prod, etc..), then what I would do is use the `ENVIRONMENT` constant defined in your index.php to decide which DB group your app should use.

This is what should already be set by default on index.php:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
```

so in database.php you can do something like this:

```
switch(ENVIRONMENT){
    case 'staging':
        $active_group = 'staging';
        break;
    case 'production':
        $active_group = 'prod';
        break;
    default:
        $active_group = 'dev';
        break;
}

$db['staging'] = [
    'dsn' => '',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => '',
];
$db['prod'] = [
    'dsn' => '',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => '',
];
$db['dev'] = [
    'dsn' => '',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => '',
];
```

Once this is done, all you have to do is worry about setting your variable `$_SERVER['CI_ENV']` which you can do in the Apache virtual host file.

> Reference: Handling Multiple Environments
>   https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/environments.html

Comment: it says file written, but not writing anything

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I am doing this to update my config file otherwise it will say invalid database configuration , it will be placed on AWS server and i am writing to a different folder altogether, but it works for normal strings, is there a way i can convert this array to a string ?

Comment: And why cant you instead modify the database.php rather then creating a new one. What ive done in the past is have two sets of arrays in database.php that look something like `$db['dev'] = [...];` and `$db['prod'] = [...];` , then all you have to do is set your "active" flag `$active_group = 'prod';` does that make sense?

Comment: exactly , i am trying to do this, since i am running a script outside codeigniter and setting up the codeigniter instance for the first use i have to write to that file else during the first login the user will get an error saying invalid database configuration

Comment: but i will have to write the config statements to the file , right ?, It should be autmatically written

Comment: yes, is your concern security?.. if thats the case, you can instead keep a config file on your server, and use `include()` to include it if the ENVIRONMENT is set to "prod"

Comment: my concern is converting object to a string and inserting it in config file present in some other folder as my install script is different

Comment: if you still want to do it in that manner, you would have to encode your array into JSON string, pass it, then decode it back to an array. Dont recommend doing all that though.